# Asp.Net MVC - Data permutator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched for hours for this without finding an answer, so I'm asking your help (I'm a beginner in web development (and in Asp.Net MVC)).

I want to create a simple data permutator (for example you enter 3 datas "a, b, and c", and I give you the possible permutations between these 3 datas : "abc; acb; bac; bca; cab; cba").

I have tried the following code, but it does not work (I have an HTTP 404 error).

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">1</div>
        <input type="text" name="firstData" class="form-control" placeholder="First Data" maxlength="50" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">2</div>
        <input type="text" name="secondData" class="form-control" placeholder="Second Data" maxlength="50" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">3</div>
        <input type="text" name="thirdData" class="form-control" placeholder="Third Data" maxlength="50" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mainAction centerbloc">
    <input type="submit" value="Permutate the data" class="btn btn-success register-button-slider" href="">
</div>
</form>
```

And then below, I want to display the result in the same page, like this :

```
@{ if (IsPost)
    {

        string firstdata = Request.Form["firstData"];
        string seconddata = Request.Form["secondData"];
        string thirddata = Request.Form["thirdData"];

        <p>
            @firstdata @seconddata @thirddata<br />
            @seconddata @firstdata @thirddata<br />
        </p>
    }
}
```

I haven't put anything special in my controller (maybe the mistake is here?) :

```
namespace Blogs.Controllers
{
    public class ToolsController : Controller
    {
        [Route("tools/datapermutator", Name = "DataPermutator"), HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DataPermutator()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a way to do it, it would be very helpful, thank you in advance!

Comment: Sow your controller methods

Comment: Thank you for your message. I edited the question, adding the controller information (I didn't put anything special in it, maybe it's where I made a mistake).

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just do this in the client using javascript/jquery? Or use ajax to post the 3 values to a controller method that generates the permutations in a partial view and then update the DOM with the partial?

Comment: I'm open to any other method that would work but I'm not finding any way to make it work. The only limitation is that I would like to be able to show the result in a popup (because I want to create a button so that the user can copy all the information in one click). Thanks

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vev4ge5q/)?